# Choosing the right power-switch with LED for a simple electrical design

Tags: electricity

I want to add an ON/OFF switch with an integrated indicator LED to a very simple electronic design, between a 9v battery and the connected module that it powers. What should I be looking at to select the power switch ( specifications ) and can I connect it like any simple power-switch ?

Comment: Welcome to EE SE! That depends on the system that the switch connected into. Two main parameters: voltage and current.

Comment: an illuminated switch consists of two usually separate devices .... one is a normal switch and the other is a lamp of some kind .... you just connect the switch same as any other switch ..... you will have to figure out how to power the LED

Comment: @jsotola ..alternative and autonomous power for the led itself? In the example linked here, wd it mean that I could power a 3v switch-led w/ a 3v battery, while the switch itself would serve switching a 220v DC power? https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32979540643.html?productId=32979540643&productSubject=5PCS-LED-bulb-night-light-button-switch-12mm-instantaneous-self-Locking-Flat-head-Round-sign-metal&spm=a2g0o.detail.1000013.5.468456edVe5oBq&gps-id=pcDetailBottomMoreThisSeller&scm=1007.13339.99734.0&scm_id=1007.13339.99734.0&scm-url=1007.13339.99734.0&pvid=39e72225-210a-4fe2-80a7-ed9419ad0899

Comment: Yes, generally the circuit feeding the LED in the switch isn't the circuit being switched on and off. I hear you say 220V DC? Are you sure it's DC? Also, be careful working with these kinds of voltages!

Comment: @LukeHappyValley It is not DC, it was an assomption to have a clear demonstration, sorry. You answered my question, thank you.